# Specify arity using only or except when importing function on Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I'm studying Elixir and when  I use `only` or `except` operators when importing functions from a module I need to specify an arity number. Why?

e.g.

```
import :math, only: [sqrt: 1]
```

or

```
import :math, except: [sin: 1, cos: 1]
```

Comment: Since this is something unique to Elixir (as far as I know) you probably should remove the erlang tag from the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Across the Erlang ecosystem functions are identified by name + arity. In most other languages you can *overload* functions by name. In other words, in the Erlang world foo/1 (that is, foo(one_arg)) is a *completely* different function than foo/2 (as in, foo(one_arg, two_arg)), but in Python or Ruby "foo" is the complete function identity and it can be invoked with a flexible number of arguments.

The *convention* is to name functions that mean the same thing the same name, especially in the case of recursively defined iterative functions like:

```
factorial(N) -> factorial(1, N).

factorial(A, 0) -> A;
factorial(A, N) -> factorial(A * N, N - 1).
```

Notice there are *two* periods, meaning there are two completely independent definitions here. We could just as well write:

```
fac(N) -> sum(1, N).

sum(A, 0) -> A;
sum(A, N) -> sum(A * N, N - 1).
```

But you will notice that the second version's savings in terms of character strokes is drastically outweighed by the convolution of its semantics -- the second version's internal function name is an outright lie!

The convention is to name related functions the same thing, but in actuality overloading functions by arity is not allowed in the Erlang ecosystem. To make such overloading acceptable would require significant feature additions to the compiler of a language that compiles to Erlang's bytecode, and that would be a pointless waste of painful effort. The current situation is about as good as we can get in a dynamically typed functional language (without it becoming a statically typed functional language... and that's another discussion entirely).

The end result is that you have to specify *exactly* what function you want to import, whether in Erlang or Elixir, and that means identifying it by name + arity. Recognizing that the common convention is to use the same name for functions that do the same thing but have different argument counts (often simply writing a cascade of curried definitions to enclose common defaults), Elixir provides a shortcut to including functions by groups instead of enumerating them.

So when you `import :math, only: [sqrt: 1]` you only take `math:sqrt/1` and left the rest of the module out (were there a `math:sqrt/2` you would have ignored it). When you `import :math, except: [sin: 1, cos: 1]` you take everything *but* `math:sin/1` and `math:cos/1` (were there a `math:sin/2` you would have taken it). The name + arity is a distinct identity. Imagine a big KV store of available functions. The keys are `{module, func, arity}`, meaning they are an atomic value to the system. If you're familiar with Erlang even a little this may strike you as familiar, because you deal with the tuple `{Module, Function, Args}` all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Functions in Erlang and Elixir are uniquely identified by module/name/arity. In order to import/exclude the correct function, you need to specify all three parts. Another way of understanding this is to consider the case of capturing function references, e.g. `&Map.get/2`.

Even if two functions share the same name, they are actually completely different functions to the VM. In order to reference the correct one, you have to correctly identify the function you wish to call, hence the need to specify all three components with `only`, `except`.