# Do Erlang or Elixir do resolve by name in a way that requires "name mangling"?

Tags: erlang, elixir, name-mangling

Does the concept of "arity" solve this problem?

I had a quick look at http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/global.html, but it mostly seems to involve node registration, not resolution by name for functions or atoms.

Does CosNaming (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/CosNaming_NamingContext.html) deal with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "name mangling"? In any case, Erlang and Elixir resolve functions explicitly by name + arity -- there is no function overloading as in C, and variadic functions cannot be defined (though depending on why you need variadic functions list arguments tend to cover this very well and be far more semantically precise). I discussed this a bit in an answer here about Elixir function imports and name resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644258/specify-arity-using-only-or-except-when-importing-function-on-elixir/26654128#26654128

Comment: // , "Name Mangling" is a pretty well-discussed term. I mean it here as the common solution to the problem of overloaded identifiers in programming languages. (An identifier is "overloaded" if the same name is used in more than one context or with more than one meaning.)

Comment: In the context of specific languages/runtimes it is well defined, but each carries a different meaning, which is why I asked (consider, for example, name mangling in C vs Python vs Java). Anyway, in the Erlang VM `name/arity` is a specific, explicit identity and cannot be gotten around. As in languages like Python that "seem to lack feature X or Y" the omission here is a mark of deliberate design, not impulsive choice, and is central to the way programmers come to think about the language. That is why I think this is a good question -- perhaps rephrased it would be a *great* question.

Comment: One caveat to this I forgot to mention (I really should put all this in an answer, but its past my bedtime... maybe tomorrow), function names are atoms, meaning that you *can indeed* refer to a function of N-arity by name if you pass the common identifier as an atom. So let's say you have `Args1 = [1,2,3]` and `Args2 = [1,2]` and two functions `foo/2` and `foo/3`. You could do `apply(Fun, Args1)` or `apply(Fun, Args2)` and the appropriate one would be selected -- which leaves the door wide open to effectively variadic or curried cascades of function defs. Just watch your types and dialyze.

Comment: // , How would you rephrase the question to its destiny of greatness, @zxq9? Also, zxq9, it seems like that first comment might mean to suggest editing my question to be about what "name mangling" means in Erlang.

Answer (score 4):

If by "name mangling" you mean the concept from C++ then no I don't think they do.

There's no function overloading in Erlang or Elixir.  (I tried to find a source to point you to but trust me--it's just not there.) Functions are picked by arity alone and the same function name with two different arities is two different functions.  f/0 is different than f/1 which is different from f/2.  As @zxq9 pointed out in the comments, due to this property there's no variable arity in Erlang or Elixir either although that can be simulated by passing lists as parameters.

This [portion](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html) of the Erlang docs discusses how Erlang figures out which function to resolve to. While the mechanism underneath is the same for Elixir the syntax is different.

Comment: This handling of functions, names and arities is built in to the VM so there is no way of getting around it. You can fake it by putting the arguments in lists as you mentioned (I've done it), but you can't get around it.